# Python inversions counter: slice indicies error

Tags: python, list, compiler-errors, slice

I'm trying to write an inversions counter that takes a list of integers as input and outputs the number of inversions.  Since it's going to handle large lists, I'm using a divide and conquer recursive approach, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\py.py", line 34, in <module>
    Inversions([1,2,3,4,5], 5)
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\py.py", line 13, in Inversions
    x = Inversions(numbers[:length/2 - 0.5], length/2-0.5)
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Here is my code:

```
def Inversions(numbers, length):
    if length == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        if length%2 == 0:
            x = Inversions(numbers[:length/2], length/2)
            y = Inversions(numbers[length/2:], length/2)
            b = sorted(numbers[:length/2], length/2)
            c = sorted(numbers[length/2:], length/2)
            z = Split(b, c)
            return x+y+z
        elif length%2 == 1:
            x = Inversions(numbers[:length/2 - 0.5], length/2-0.5)
            y = Inversions(numbers[length/2 - 0.5:], length/2-0.5)
            b = sorted(numbers[:length/2 - 0.5], length/2-0.5)
            c = sorted(numbers[length/2 - 0.5:], length/2-0.5)
            z = Split(b, c)
            return x+y+z
def Split(first, second):
    i = 1
    j = 1
    d = []
    inversions = 0
    for k in range(1,len(b)+1):
        if b[i] < C[j]:
            d[k] = b[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            d[k] = c[j]
            inversions += len(b[i:])
            j += 1
    return inversions

Inversions([1,2,3,4,5], 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`length` is even, which results in a non-integral float. Use integer division instead.

```
x = Inversions(numbers[:length // 2], length // 2)
```

Comment: Still getting the error on the line where the list indices are length//2 - 0.5.  Tried changing them to 1/2, didn't work.  How do I make these integers and not floats?  Also note the example list has odd length, so it should be passed to the elif statement, not the if statement.

Comment: I'll give you a bit more time to... think it out.

Comment: double slashes on the 1/2's, got it.  Thank you.  Got a different error now, but if it's not one thing, it's another.